# building a shell command inside python function based on different conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have written the below python function which is working fine but there are lot of code which looks redundant to me and hence i want to make it better by using best coding guidelines.

Basically I am trying to build either a gcloud command or a simple bash command to execute a python script which depends upon the `spark_flag` parameter which is an input to the function and is FALSE by default.

```
def build_command(table_info1, table_info2, date_folder, timestamp,spark_flag):
    try:
        run_cmd_str = " nohup /usr/local/airflow/dags/batch_ingestion.py -- "
        if table_info1[0] == 'db2':
            app_name = "data-pipeline-" + table_info1[0] + "-" + table_info1[5] + "-" + table_info1[
                6] + "-" + timestamp + table_info2[10]
            if spark_flag:
                cmd_str = "gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster={}  --region={} --id {} --properties spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.driver.memory=512m,spark.executor.memory=512m,spark.executor.cores=1,spark.executor.instances=1 --jars /usr/local/airflow/dags/batch_ingestion.py -- ".format(
                table_info1[10], table_info1[11], app_name)
            else:
                cmd_str = run_cmd_str

        elif table_info1[0] == 'sql_server' or table_info1[0] == 'azure_sql':
            if '.' in table_info1[6]:
                table = table_info1[6].split('.')
                app_name = "data-pipeline-" + table_info1[0] + "-" + table_info1[5] + "-" + table[0] + "_" + table[
                    1] + "-" + timestamp + table_info2[10]
            else:
                app_name = "data-pipeline-" + table_info1[0] + "-" + table_info1[5] + "-" + table_info1[
                    6] + "-" + timestamp + table_info2[10]
            if spark_flag:
                cmd_str = "gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster={}  --region={} --id {} --properties spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.driver.memory=512m,spark.executor.memory=512m,spark.executor.cores=1,spark.executor.instances=1 --jars /usr/local/airflow/dags/batch_ingestion.py -- ".format(
                table_info1[10], table_info1[11], app_name)
            else:
                cmd_str=run_cmd_str

        elif table_info1[0] == 'abc_informix' or table_info1[0] == 'def_informix':

            if table_info1[7] != '-1':
                app_name = "data-pipeline-" + table_info1[0] + "-" + table_info1[5] + "-" + table_info1[6] + "-" + \
                           table_info1[7] + "-" + timestamp + table_info2[10]
            elif table_info1[7] == '-1' and table_info1[0] == 'def_informix':
                app_name = "data-pipeline-" + table_info1[0] + "-" + table_info1[5] + "-" + table_info1[
                    6] + "-" + timestamp + table_info2[10]
            if spark_flag:
                cmd_str = "gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster={}  --region={} --id {}  --properties spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.driver.memory=512m,spark.executor.memory=512m,spark.executor.cores=1,spark.executor.instances=1 /usr/local/airflow/dags/batch_ingestion.py -- ".format(
                table_info1[10], table_info1[11], app_name)
            else:
                cmd_str = run_cmd_str

        last_run_dated = str(table_info2[1]).split(None, 1)[0]
        cmd_string = " ".join(
            [cmd_str, table_info1[0], table_info1[5], table_info1[6], table_info1[7], table_info1[1], table_info1[2],
             table_info1[3], table_info1[8], table_info1[4], table_info2[0], last_run_dated, table_info2[2],
             date_folder, table_info2[5], table_info2[6], table_info2[7], table_info2[3], table_info2[4],
             table_info2[9]])

        return cmd_string, app_name

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: @TobySpeight Done. I've updated the title now.

Comment: Don't put a line break in the middle of a subscript -- `table_info1[6]` should not be split across lines.

Comment: Assign meaningful names to the list elements, rather than using all those hard-coded subscripts. `name1, name2, name3, ... = table_info1`

Comment: Which Python version do you use? If not 3.10, can you change to a higher version?

Answer (score 1):

The `spark_flag` `if`-statement can be factored out. Then we can set a default `app_name` and overwrite it when needed.

```py
def build_command(table_info1, table_info2, date_folder, timestamp, spark_flag):

    # Default app_name
    app_name = f"data-pipeline-{table_info1[0]}-{table_info1[5]}-{table_info1[6]}-{timestamp}{table_info2[10]}"

    # Change app_name in a couple of cases
    if table_info1[0] in ('sql_server', 'azure_sql',) and '.' in table_info1[6]:
        table = table_info1[6].split('.')
        app_name = f"data-pipeline-{table_info1[0]}-{table_info1[5]}-{table[0]}_{table[1]}-{timestamp}{table_info2[10]}"

    elif table_info1[0] in ('abc_informix', 'def_informix',) and table_info1[7] != '-1' and table_info1[0] != 'def_informix':
        app_name = f"data-pipeline-{table_info1[0]}-{table_info1[5]}-{table_info1[6]}-{table_info1[7]}-{timestamp}{table_info2[10]}"


    if spark_flag:
        cmd_str = f"gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster={table_info1[10]}  --region={table_info1[11]} --id {app_name} --properties spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.driver.memory=512m,spark.executor.memory=512m,spark.executor.cores=1,spark.executor.instances=1 --jars /usr/local/airflow/dags/batch_ingestion.py -- "
    else:
        cmd_str = " nohup /usr/local/airflow/dags/batch_ingestion.py -- "


    last_run_dated = str(table_info2[1]).split(None, 1)[0]

    cmd_string = " ".join([
        cmd_str,
        table_info1[0], table_info1[5], table_info1[6], table_info1[7], table_info1[1], table_info1[2],
        table_info1[3], table_info1[8], table_info1[4], table_info2[0], last_run_dated, table_info2[2],
        date_folder, table_info2[5], table_info2[6], table_info2[7], table_info2[3], table_info2[4],
        table_info2[9]
    ])

    return cmd_string, app_name
```

But as others have commented, the different `table_info` parts should be given descriptive names.

Comment: what name should i give in place of table_info ?i am a bit confused

Comment: The name `table_info` is okay, but you could introduce a variable for `table_info1[0]` and another for `table_info1[1]` and so on. What does `table_info1[0]` contain? What does `table_info1[1]` contain?